# My value for this always equals 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
 tests = int(input("Enter the number of tests needed: "))
 goal = int(input("Enter the desired sum: "))
 counter1 = 0
 counter = 0
 total = 0

while counter != tests:
      counter = counter + 1

      while counter1 != goal:
            total = total + counter1 **2
            counter1 = counter1 + 1
            print(total)
```

Here is the direct question from my homework, i added more stuff, but now it goes on infinitely: Write  a program to calculate the sum of squares like 1^2 + 2^2 etc, it should keep going till a sum is reached, output sum every time and do it for a specified number of tests.

The program is supposed to loop till desired sum is reached and out put each total every time, but no total appears to be printed.

Comment: That's because unless the user types `1`, the `while` loop will never execute because `counter` never equals `goal`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think you want ``while counter != goal:`` or perhaps ``while counter < goal:``. As is, this will only run if ``counter`` and ``goal`` are equal.

Comment: I did aruisdante's method and entered the value 10, but it keeps going till 10 values are outputted, but it should stop at the value 5 because it is the closest to the sum 10.

Comment: I edited most of it and made it simple to understand

Comment: What's the difference between `counter` and `counter1`? You never modify either `counter` or `tests` inside the loop, only `counter1`, which means if the expression is true and you enter the loop, the loop never terminates.

Answer (score 1):

You need :

```
`counter <= goal:`
```

in your loop. The while tests whether the expression is true and if its true, then the content in the loop is executed. You want to execute it als long as counter and goal are not the same. The right expression for it is: `counter <= goal:`